# REGEXMATCH doesn't match, but should work

Tags: google-sheets, regex

Why the following REGEXMATCH results FALSE?

```
=REGEXMATCH("aaa E: 111 111 bbb"; " E: ([\d\s]+) bbb")
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, the "aaa E: 111 111 bbb" string had special character instead of space.
When I replaced the space in "111 111" the result became TRUE.

So it was a special character instead space, this is why the formula was FALSE originally.

Problem solved.